# Tensorflow module not found by Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, virtualenv, jupyter

**Problem:**  Jupyter says "Module not found" when I try to import Tensorflow on Mac.

**Background:**

- Virtualenv 16.7.9 installed & activated (venv)
- Python 3.7.6 installed
- PIP 19.3.1 installed
- Tensorflow 2.1.0 installed using PIP as per [official install instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3)

At the command line, I can activate venv, start python3 then import tensorflow and display the tensorflow version correctly. But Tensorflow won't import from within Jupiter. And if I try to change the kernel within a Jupyter notebook, only Python3 is listed.

On other threads, people recommend using anaconda, but I've used PIP to install Tensorflow as recommended in the above link.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Install a Jupyter Kernel

You need to install a kernel inside the env and then use Jupyter.

```
ipython kernel install --user --name=.venv
```

Then restart jupyter, click new, you should see `.venv` in your kernel list.

Comment: Thanks. Your ipython command added the venv kernel successfully. Jupyter still displayed the Module not found error. This seems to be resolved after I ran the tensorflow pip install command from within a Jupyter Notebook (instead of from terminal > venv). Only did a basic test as it's late, but it worked without errors.